# Сериализация ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как сериализовать класс с коллекцией вида ObservableCollection`?

Пытаюсь делать на классе `Example`.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Example
{
    public string Properties1 { get; set; } = "nothing";
    public bool Properties2 { get; set; }
    public static ObservableCollection<Animal> MyCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();  
    public Example()
    {
        MyCollection.Add(new Animal() { Sound = "Мяу"});
        MyCollection.Add(new Animal() { Sound = "Гав" });
    }
}
```

Сериализую так, но сериализуются только свойства:

```
Example example = new Example();

XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, example);
}
```

Comment: А чего у вас коллекция статик то? Её ессна и нет в экземпляре. Сериализуйте саму коллекцию, если нужна только она.

Comment: @Monk: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD так может это опечатка, непонятно.

Comment: @Monk, Нет, не опечатка :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При сериализации экземпляра статические свойства класса не сериализуются.

Так что, либо `MyCollection` должен быть нестатическим, либо весь класс класс переделывать на синглтон.